# React js ( animation when it is clicked )

Tags: reactjs

I want to know when i click on react icon it should rotate 180deg and again when i[![enter image description here][1]][1] click it should rotate to 0 deg.  In react js.

➡

Answer (score 0):

You can use css **transform** and **transition**. Just add a state in your Icon Component to keep track of rotated or not

```
class RotateIcon extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
          rotated: false
        };
    }

    onIconClicked = () => {
        this.setState({ rotated: !this.state.rotated });
    };

    render() {
      const degree = this.state.rotated ? '180' : '0';
      return (
         <Icon // Whatever your icon is called
           style={{
             transform: `rotate(${degree}deg)`,
             transition: 'transform 200ms linear' // update time here  
           }} 
           onClick={this.onIconClicked} 
         /> 
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working.

Plz help me out without transation only

Comment: Please add code of what you tried in your post. That way it’ll be easier to help you 